# Creating a C++ .Net Core wrapper for native library results in error LNK2028

Tags: c++, .net, .net-core, srt

I'm trying to create a managed (.net core) C++/CLI wrapper for a native library ([Srt](https://github.com/Haivision/srt)) but when referencing methods in the native lib I'm getting 2 build errors. I've referenced the headers `srt.h` from the native library, tried calling a method named `srt_cleanup` but get this on build:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000B) "extern "C" int __cdecl srt_cleanup(void)" (?srt_cleanup@@$$J0YAHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall HeliosMediaStreamCliSrt::SrtReceiver::Stop(void)" (?Stop@SrtReceiver@HeliosMediaStreamCliSrt@@$$FQE$AAMXXZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl srt_cleanup(void)" (?srt_cleanup@@$$J0YAHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall HeliosMediaStreamCliSrt::SrtReceiver::Stop(void)" (?Stop@SrtReceiver@HeliosMediaStreamCliSrt@@$$FQE$AAMXXZ)
```

Sample:

```
// pch.h
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include <srt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif //PCH_H
```

```
// SrtReceiver.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace TestSrt {
    public ref class SrtReceiver {
    public:
        void SrtReceiver::Stop();

    private:
    };
}
```

```c
// SrtReceiver.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "SrtReceiver.h"
namespace TestSrt {
    void SrtReceiver::Stop() {
        srt_cleanup();
    }
}
```

Project Configuration:

```
General -> Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
Advanced -> Common Language Runtime Support: .NET Core Runtime Support (/clr:netcore)
Advanced -> .NET Core Target Framework: .NET 5.0
C/C++ -> General -> Common Language Runtime Support: NetCore
```

I'm pretty rusty with C++ so I'm unfamiliar with the build system and its resulting in confusing errors. I've never tried doing anything with .net core in c++ before as C# is more my speed. This looks like something to do with build properties and the compiler is looking for the wrong internal method names. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I simply forgot to include the paths to the .lib files in `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: /path/to/srt.lib`

Simple, but spent hours of google searching to no avail. Hopefully this helps out other a C++ beginners as I didn't come across it.